# Access current URI of Nokogiri HTML Document

Tags: ruby, url, nokogiri, mechanize

I need to access the url of the page I am currently on (which is saved as an Nokogiri HTML Document) to fetch certain parameters from it. Here is what I've tried:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('some.url.com/?parameter1=234').parser
page.uri.match(/\/\?parameter1=(\d*)/)[1].to_s
```

As you can see I want to extract the value of the parameter1.

Any thoughts on how to go about that will be much appreciated!

NOTE!
It's not an option o remove the .parser method, since I need it further down in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `agent.history.last.uri.to_s`